# Spark 2.3 - get files name with sc.textFile?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add filename to each Row while inserting in DB. Getting folder as input.

Loading folder using `textFile(...)` method:

```
public JavaRDD<Row> readFolder(String filePath) {

   JavaRDD<String> logRDD = sparkContext.textFile(filePath, 1).toJavaRDD();

   RegexMatch reg = new RegexMatch();
   JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = logRDD
           .map((Function<String, Row>) line -> {
               String[] sp = line.split(" ");
               // want to add file name to Row, how to get it ?
               return RowFactory.create(sp[1], sp[3], sp[2]); 
           });

   rowRDD.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());

   return rowRDD;
}
```

Changed this code to `wholeTextFiles(...)`, getting filename here, but not sure how to get Row out of it, similar to above code ?

```
public void readFolder(String filePath) {
    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkContext);
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> fileNameContentsRDD = javaSparkContext.wholeTextFiles(filePath, 1);

    JavaRDD<String> lineCounts = fileNameContentsRDD.map((Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>) fileNameContent -> {
        String content = fileNameContent._2();
        int numLines = content.split("[\r\n]+").length;

        return fileNameContent._1() + ":  " + numLines;
    });

    List<String> output = lineCounts.collect();
    System.out.println(output);

}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine both as

```
public JavaRDD<Row> readFolder(String filePath) {
    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkContext);
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> fileNameContentsRDD = javaSparkContext.wholeTextFiles(filePath, 1);

    JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = fileNameContentsRDD.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, String>, Row>) fileNameContent -> {
        String fileName = fileNameContent._1();
        String content = fileNameContent._2();
        String[] lines = content.split("[\r\n]+");
        List<Row> array = new ArrayList<Row>(lines.length);
        for(String line : lines){
            String[] sp = line.split(" ");
            array.add(RowFactory.create(fileName, sp[1], sp[3], sp[2]));
        }
        return array.iterator();
    });

    return rowRDD;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Spark 2.3 use the SparkSession API to read the text file,

```
Dataset<String> textDS = session.read().textFile(filePath);
```

then you can use this to get the input filename,

```
String fileName = textDS.inputFiles()[0];
```

use `textDS.toJavaRDD()` to convert the `Dataset` to the `rdd` and apply your logic.